# Is there is any R function to find out the latest score and time recorded from data frame

Tags: r, data-cleaning, mutate

I Have four type of pain score which is recorded initially and also repeated after sometime, The pain score recorded differs with person ID , I want to find out the last recorded score type ,score and time. If the second recorded score is NA and if there is only one score recorded before that then value and time should return as NA.I have created a minimum reproducible data and output of dput as below:
Desired output : "last_recorded_score_name" , last_recorded_score" , last recorded_score_time

```
structure(list(
        PersonID = c(111, 222, 333), 
        NumericalPainScore = c(1, 3, NA), 
        NumericalOneTime = structure(c(1654132800, 1654134000, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        FlaccRestScore = c(3, NA, 1), 
        FlaccRestOneTime = structure(c(1654123560, NA, 1654131600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        FlaccActivityScore = c(NA, NA, 2), 
        FlaccActivityTime = structure(c(NA, NA, 1654128000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        WongBakerScale = c(NA, 1, NA), 
        WongBakerOneTime = structure(c(NA, 1654137600, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        Numerical2ndScore = c(1, 3, NA), 
        Numerical2ndTime = structure(c(1654136400, 1654137600, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        FlaccRest2ndScore = c(3, NA, 1), 
        FlaccRest2ndTime = structure(c(1654127160, NA, 1654135200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        FlaccActivity2ndScore = c(NA, NA, 2), 
        FlaccActivity2ndTime = structure(c(NA, NA, 1654124400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        WongBaker2ndScale = c(NA, 1, NA), 
        WongBaker2ndTime = structure(c(NA, 1654141200, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), 
        class = "data.frame", 
        row.names = c(NA,-3L)
    )
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the desired output with these data? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
quux %>%
  pivot_longer(-PersonID, names_pattern = "(.*)(Score|Time|Scale)", names_to = c("K",".value")) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = Time, by = PersonID)
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   PersonID K            Score Time                Scale
#      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1      111 Numerical2nd     1 2022-06-02 02:20:00    NA
# 2      222 WongBaker2nd    NA 2022-06-02 03:40:00     1
# 3      333 FlaccRest2nd     1 2022-06-02 02:00:00    NA
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(PersonID = c(111, 222, 333), NumericalPainScore = c(1, 3, NA), NumericalOneTime = structure(c(1654132800, 1654134000, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), FlaccRestScore = c(3, NA, 1), FlaccRestOneTime = structure(c(1654123560, NA, 1654131600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), FlaccActivityScore = c(NA, NA, 2), FlaccActivityTime = structure(c(NA, NA, 1654128000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), WongBakerScale = c(NA, 1, NA), WongBakerOneTime = structure(c(NA,  1654137600, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), Numerical2ndScore = c(1, 3, NA), Numerical2ndTime = structure(c(1654136400, 1654137600, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), FlaccRest2ndScore = c(3, NA, 1), FlaccRest2ndTime = structure(c(1654127160, NA, 1654135200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), FlaccActivity2ndScore = c(NA, NA, 2), FlaccActivity2ndTime = structure(c(NA, NA, 1654124400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), WongBaker2ndScale = c(NA,  1, NA), WongBaker2ndTime = structure(c(NA, 1654141200, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```